# Python: obtaining a value per group using a hierarchical structure in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following data:

```
df =
id interval name
1  8        A
1  8        B
1  8        C
2  2        B
2  2        C
2  3        A
```

I want to have a name per id and interval. In particular, I want A over B and C and B over C. Such as:

```
df =
id interval name
1  8        A
2  2        B
2  3        A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indexes by minimal values:

```
df['name'] = pd.Categorical(df['name'], categories=['A','B','C'], ordered=True)

df = df.loc[df.groupby(['id','interval'])['name'].idxmin()]
```

Or:

```
df['name'] = pd.Categorical(df['name'], categories=['A','B','C'], ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values('name').drop_duplicates(['id','interval']).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   id  interval name
0   1         8    A
1   2         2    B
2   2         3    A
```

Another idea with mapping with dictionary generated by `enumerate`:

```
d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(['A','B','C'])}

df = df.loc[df['name'].map(d).groupby([df['id'],df['interval']]).idxmin()]
print (df)
   id  interval name
0   1         8    A
3   2         2    B
5   2         3    A
```